# Border color cell, prevent change color when in focus

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which I dynamically change the border color depending on the contents. The problem is, when I put focus on a particular cell of this table, the border automatically turns blue, which is apparently the default. Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening? I tried playing around in the css with the input.focus of this table, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: probably `input {outline:none;}`

Comment: Beautiful! That did the trick. Thanks so much Alon.

Answer (score 1):

if you focus on input field you should use
  #YourID:focus {outline: none;}

also this trick is not useful in the case of div tag.
for div tags you should use jquery.